# Name for class of (almost) convex functions

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, vector-analysis

Is there a name for the class of functions $\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$ $f:\R^n \to \R$ such that for each $f$, there exists an $\alpha > 0$ such that $$f(x) + \frac{\alpha}{2} \Vert x \Vert^2$$
is convex? I'm aware of the definition of a strongly convex function, this would correspond to letting $\alpha < 0$ per the conventions of that definition. This class should at least contain the Lipschitz functions (I believe), though I'm unsure if it is equal.

Comment: One name for this class is *$\alpha$-weakly convex*.